# Does removing password improve security?

Tags: passwords

I use a large assortment of software, each requiring it's own password.
Some of these applications remove the password after a failed login attempt, where others leave it populated.

Does it improve security, or is it more of a user interface choice?

Answer (score 5):

This wouldn't improve security, this is entirely a user experience decision.

Comment: And regarding UX it's actually quite annoying. I often know that "if I have a typo, it's most likely the last character", then the program deletes the whole input. :(